# Não consigo armazenar os dados no meu banco variavel outros2

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){     
        $categoria = $_POST ['categoria'];
        $origem = $_POST ['origem'];
        $acao = $_POST['acoes'];
        $responsavel = $_POST ['responsavel'];
        $quando = $_POST ['quando'];
        $status = $_POST ['status'];
        $tema = $_POST['tema'];
        $chave = $_POST['chave'];
        $outros1 = $_POST['outros1'];
        $outros2 = $_POST['outros2'];




        /**
        *Valida o Formulário
        */


        if($origem == ""){
             echo "<script>Notification.showAlert('Preencha o Campo Origem!');</script>";

        }else if($acao == ""){
            echo "<script>Notification.showAlert('Preencha o Campo Ação!');</script>";    

        }else if(($responsavel == "" ) || ($outros1 == "") ){
            echo "<script>Notification.showAlert('Preencha o Campo Responsável!')</script>";    

        }else if(($quando == "" ) || ($outros2 == "") ){
            echo "<script>Notification.showAlert('Preencha o Campo Quando!')</script>";    

        }else if($tema == ""){
            echo "<script>Notification.showAlert('Preencha o Campo tema!')</script>";    

        }else{

        if ($outros1 == ""){

        $dbc = mysqli_connect('meusite', 'root', 'rede', 'portal');
            $query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$responsavel', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            mysqli_close($dbc);


            echo "<script>alert('Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!')</script>";    
        }
        else{    

            $dbc = mysqli_connect('meusite', 'root', 'rede', 'portal');
            $query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$outros1', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            mysqli_close($dbc);


            echo "<script>alert('Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!')</script>";

        }

        if($outros2 == ""){

        $dbc = mysqli_connect('meusite', 'root', 'rede', 'portal');
            $query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$responsavel', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            mysqli_close($dbc);


            echo "<script>alert('Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!')</script>";

        }
        else{

            $dbc = mysqli_connect('meusite', 'root', 'rede', 'portal');
            $query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$outros1', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            mysqli_close($dbc);


            echo "<script>alert('Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!')</script>";

        }

    }    

    }
```

//Não consigo  armazenar a variavel do outros2, somente consigo do outros1, acho que erro de logica nos if else das condições para o banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro simples na hora de salvar apenas, o erro está na query, **você está salvando $outros1** onde deveria ser **$outros2** pelo que entendi.

Na segunda parte, quando você verifica o **$outros2**,

```
if ($outros2 == ""){ ... }
```

No `else`, você está salvando com **$outros1**:

```
else {
// ...
$query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$outros1', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";

}
```

Correto com **$outros2**:

```
else {
// ...
$query = "INSERT INTO PlanoAcao(categoria, origem, acoes, responsavel, quando, status, tema, chave) values ('$categoria', '$origem', '$acao', '$outros2', '$quando', '$status', '$tema', '$chave')";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue armazenar a variável `$outros2` porque ela não está sendo inserida em nenhuma das suas `querys`. Nas quatro `querys` que você criou nenhuma existe a variável `$outros2`.